# PowerBI plot current years values vs average of all previous years from dataset

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset and I'm trying to display the current years precipitation sum vs avg of previous years.

[image]

I want to display average line like this

[image]

I've tried grouping by month, but has not helped me

Comment: Your question is very vague. What exactly are you struggling with? The chart? The measure? The data?

Comment: Hi @teylyn I want to display an average line that runs across this bar chart displaying the average precipitation of the last 10 years

Comment: You need to remove the year from the evaluation context So you'd do something like CALCULATE ( AVERAGE('Table'[Rainfall]), REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar'[Year]) )

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to remove years (partially) from the evaluation context of the average. All years prior to the current year (I guess that means a static current year, so 2024 as of this writing). You could do that part by creating a variable and calculating that first (nice because you can declare a static date, like '01-Jan-2007' and then work with wonky data like AdventureWorks, and later change that to

```
VAR CurrentDate = TODAY()
```

and you don't have to dig into the guts of your measure to change anything else. You'd just substitute that for DimDate(Calendar[Year])

```
    Avg OrderQty Prev Years = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('FactInternetSales'[OrderQuantity]),
    /* removes the current year from the evaluation context */
    FILTER(
        ALL('DimDate'[CalendarYear]),
        [CalendarYear]<MAX('DimDate'[CalendarYear])
    )
)
```

Then you'd use that for your line measure.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do the same, I grouped by month and created a column sum, and another column to count the no of months, I then dicided the sum by count to get average precipitation per month.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wId1V.png)
here is my visual

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m65FC.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).